# Filter query to get chat messages among two friends?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create a chat api, i have structured the messages model to look like this

```
class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="user")
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="sender")
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="reciever")
    message = models.CharField(max_length=10000000000)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now i am trying to write the API view to get all messages that belongs only to **me** and the **person** that i am chatting with.

Let me elaborate: Let's say **Destiny** is texting **Sammy**, there would definitely be alot of messages that have been sent between me (Destiny) and the user (Sammy), so i want to get all that text.

This is the view that i have written to do this

```
class GetMessages(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        sender_id = self.kwargs['sender_id']
        reciever_id = self.kwargs['reciever_id']
        messages =  ChatMessage.objects.filter(sender=sender_id, reciever=reciever_id)
        return messages
```

urls

```
    path("api/get-messages/<sender_id>/<reciever_id>/", views.GetMessages.as_view()),
```

This is what this view returns

```
## url - http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-messages/2/1/
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "sender": 2,
        "reciever": 1,
        "message": "Hey Destiny",
        "is_read": false
    }
]
```

if i swap the sender_id and reciever_id, this is the response i get

```
# url - http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-messages/1/2/
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "sender": 1,
        "reciever": 2,
        "message": "Hello Sammy",
        "is_read": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "sender": 1,
        "reciever": 2,
        "message": "This is another message for you sammy",
        "is_read": false
    }
]
```

what i want is this, when i pass in the id of the sender (1) and id of the reciever (2) in the url, i want to get a response like this, which is all the conversaion that this two folks have had.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "sender": 1,
        "reciever": 2,
        "message": "Hello Sammy",
        "is_read": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "sender": 2,
        "reciever": 1,
        "message": "Hey Destiny",
        "is_read": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "sender": 1,
        "reciever": 2,
        "message": "This is another message for you sammy",
        "is_read": false
    }
]
```

Some images
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this method,

```py
messages = ChatMessage.objects.filter(
    sender__in=[sender_id, reciever_id], reciever__in=[reciever_id, sender_id]
)
```

Comment: That would also return messages a user sends to themselves (this is possible in most chat systems). The user A will be able to see user B's private chats with themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) here:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
```

then

```py
messages = ChatMessage.objects.filter(
    Q(sender=sender_id, reciever=reciever_id) | 
    Q(sender=reciever_id, reciever=sender_id)
)
```

As a side note, it's spelled `receiver`.